# MySQL: Getting all columns in a table in a certain database

Tags: mysql, information-schema

I have several databases that have tables with the same name.

I mean, I got the following databases
`mydb1`, `mydb2`, etc

and each mydb has a table called `myTable`. But these tables have diffenet columns:

```
myTable in mydb1
id, name, age

myTable in mydb2
id, name, street, size
```

Now, if I had only one Database `mydb1` then I also had only one Table `MyTable`. If I wanted to know all the columns in that table I would make the following sql request

```
use information_schema;
select column_name from columns where table_name = 'myTable';
```

In that case this works fine, I get the columns I'm looking for.

But, in my case I have several tables called MyTable in different Databases. And the same sql request yields:

```
id, name, age, id, name, street, size
```

But I just want to have the columns of `mydb1.myTable`.

How can I get only the columnnames from just one `myTable`?

Hint: I just want to have the column names not the type, nulls oder keys. Therefore the request `show columns from mydb1.myTable` is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand. You can see in my post what I tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TABLE_SCHEMA` column in the `columns` table contains the database name, so you can do it like this:

```
select column_name from columns where table_name = 'myTable' AND table_schema = 'mydb1';
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I personally think that column name table_schema doesn't make much sence for a column that contains the database name.